# Как избавиться от задвоенного запроса DELETE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

Всем привет!

Использую Rails 5.1.4.
При выполнении первой строки кода в методе

```
def sign_out
 current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
 cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 self.current_user = nil
end
```

rails возвращает ошибку **undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass**

При этом изменения в БД, подразумеваемые данной строчкой происходят. Очень долго пытался понять как такое возможно, и при анализе логов сервера выяснил, что запрос, инициализирующий данный метод почему-то происходит дважды и как видно из логов(ниже) в одну и ту же секунду. Первывый DELETE запрос срабатывает корректно, второй - уже натыкантся на nil и возвращает ошибку.
Собственно сам вопрос - откуда берётся второй запрос DELETE и как от него избавиться? Всю голову уже сломал, заранее спасибо)))
Ниже логи сервера

Started DELETE "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 **at 2017-12-31 12:03:03** +0700
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ZJHZcGPylgSn973sZm3S9jSLWKOlQgmpyEIF8fMvA2YXNeBzI4oyDlXcMveH2KDj5I/lbnIFdzhliCwqWzq7WQ=="}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = ? LIMIT ?  [["remember_token", "481d50edab2574b6353efeaf4ad875ea0f9689e6"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["remember_token", "555"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-31 05:03:03.860653"], ["id", 4]]
   (9.2ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 10.5ms)

Started DELETE "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 **at 2017-12-31 12:03:03** +0700
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ZJHZcGPylgSn973sZm3S9jSLWKOlQgmpyEIF8fMvA2YXNeBzI4oyDlXcMveH2KDj5I/lbnIFdzhliCwqWzq7WQ=="}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = ? LIMIT ?  [["remember_token", "481d50edab2574b6353efeaf4ad875ea0f9689e6"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass):

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:24:in `sign_out'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:25:in`destroy'

Comment: По всей видимости, два запроса послал браузер. Смотрите там. Но метод надо бы прикрыть фильтром "человек залогинен", чтобы избежать 500'ки и показать более осмысленное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо, фильтрую через "флажок" singed_in? через проверку current_user.nil? А что конкретно стоит в браузере посмотреть?

Comment: Сколько запросов сделано по мнению браузера и почему (чем они вызваны).

Comment: Вы оказались правы - в других браузерах (UWB, Chrome) все запросы уходят корректно, т.е. по одному. В мозиле по прежнему - 2. Разбираемся с мозилой...

Comment: А дальше просто мистика: при включенном Network monitor в мозиле все выполняется корректно, браузер отправляет 1 запрос. Выключаю Network Monitor, той же ссылклой инициализирую тот же запрос, результат - снова задвоенный запрос "Delete" и ошибка.

Comment: может это не в тему, но всем рекомендую использовать gem `devise` аутентификацией пользователей и управления сессией.

Comment: Дублирование запросов возможно если используются turbolinks например, или некоторые скрипты подключены дважды (случайно)